# NgRx, может кто-то посоветует туториалы? В документации толком нету даже

Tags: angular, ngrx

Всем привет! Прошу прощения за такой вопрос. Я действительно искал книги по NgRx, не нашел. Зашел на сайт документации. Там трудно разобраться. Книги на русском не нашел. Есть лишь на англ. Может кто-то, знает на русском? Какой-либо туториал. Спасибо заранее. Или есть аналог NgRx? Я толком не разбираюсь, просто где-то прочитал что NgRx надо знать к ангуляру.

Comment: необязательно, ангуляр сделан, чтобы писать там всё на сервисах

Comment: чтобы найти туториал по ngrx: пишешь в ютуб поиске ngrx и находишь туториалы

Comment: Спасибо. Забыл в ютубе искать.

Comment: Полно информации на любом языке.. [Angular: понятное введение в NGRX](https://habr.com/ru/post/489674/), [Angular: пример использования NGRX](https://habr.com/ru/post/489758/)

Comment: Спасибо еще раз за ответ.